# After updated ..not to refresh page

Tags: mysql, ajax, hyperlink, pagination

In pagination.php page I have code that allow me to change the text from "activate" to "Deactivate" or "Deactivate" to "activate' in each row by clicking the link using ajax it will auto update into mysql database and then refresh into first page in pagination.php...

please see the code ...

in pagination.php jquery code....

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "action.php",
data: { status: "<?php echo $_GET['pid'];?>" }
    })
```

in action.php code...

```
<?php 
include('db.php'); 
if(isset($_GET['status'])) 
{ 
$status1=$_GET['status']; 
$select=mysql_query("select * from product where product_id='$status1'"); 
while($row=mysql_fetch_object($select)) 
{ 
$status_var=$row->status; 
if($status_var=='0') 
{ 
$status_state=1; 
} 
else 
{ 
$status_state=0; 
} 
$update=mysql_query("update product set status='$status_state' where product_id='$status1' "); 
if($update) 
{ 
header("Location: pagination.php"); 
} 
else 
{ 
echo mysql_error(); 
} 
} 
?> 
<?php 
}  
?>
```

These code are works great, but the problem is that in pagination.php, if I'm in second or any other pages page,  and when I changed text link it will refresh pagination.php page into back to first page, my question is that how can solve by not refresh the page and stay in same page after change the link!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
header("Location: pagination.php");
```

This one redirect on the first page - pagination.php. Try this

```
header("Location: pagination.php".($_GET['page'] ? '?page='.$_GET['page']:''));
```

Comment: thanks, I have tried that and not working is going back to first page instead of any other page. Maybe i put wrong function name, instead the page function name is  // Paginating
    for ($i=1; $i<=$totalpages; $i++) {
        if ($i == $thecurrentpage) { 
          echo '<span class="currently_page">' . $i .'</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;';
        }  ........... so in location code i put like this ($_GET['thecurrentpag'] still is not working ....

Comment: Please edit your post and insert into it paginator source code

Comment: so if I insert into paginator code what is ajax code is going to be! is Like this $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "pagination.php",
data: { status: "<?php echo $_GET['pid'];?>" }
    })  is this correct!

Comment: i put in pagination.php page and I'm still getting same result is going back to first page, i used this header("Location: pagination.php".($_GET['page'] ? '?page='.$_GET['page']:'')); and in declare code i put $thecurrentpage = $_GET["page"];
 if ($thecurrentpage == "")
 $thecurrentpage = 1;
 $thepreviouspage = $thecurrentpage - 1;
 $thenextpage = $thecurrentpage + 1;

Comment: Ok, then don't use redirect. Just Add page number to urls when you generate paginator links.

Comment: When i'm in the page 2 of pagination, see url address pagination/pagination.php?cat=&rows=10&page=2 so how can i write in location code ... i had trouble with that!

Comment: rebulid you question, i don't understand the problem

Comment: sorry for not clear, in pagination let say i'm in second page which is page two, and the url showing "header("Location: http://pagination.php?cat=&rows=10&page=2");" so in in location code i put like this ...for testing only ..header("Location: http://pagination.php?cat=&rows=10&page=2"); and still going to first page instead of second page!